# EPPlus: Copy Style to a range

Tags: c#, copy, range, epplus

i would like to insert x-new rows/columns to a worksheet and apply the style of the row/column from which was inserted (backgroundcolor/border etc).

This is how i add new rows:

```
xlsSheet.InsertRow(18, RowCount);
```

Then i would like to copy/apply the style of the "base" row to the new inserted rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
{
    xlsSheet.Cells[16, 1, 16, xlsSheet.Dimension.End.Column].Copy(xlsSheet.Cells[16 + i + 1, 1]);
}
```

But this code doesnt copy/apply the style of the "base" rows. At this moment i have a workaround with interop, but this takes years in comparison to epplus. :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the 4.0.4 code:

```
if (copyStylesFromRow > 0)
{
    var cseS = new CellsStoreEnumerator<int>(_styles, copyStylesFromRow, 0, copyStylesFromRow, ExcelPackage.MaxColumns); //Fixes issue 15068 , 15090
    while(cseS.Next())
    {
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            _styles.SetValue(rowFrom + r, cseS.Column, cseS.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

it uses the copyStylesFromRow value but because of the sequence of code, it uses the new row numbers. So if you wanted to insert 4 rows starting in row 3:

```
workbook.Worksheets[1].InsertRow(3,4,6);
```

This inserts a 4 new rows starting in row 3, because row 3 is included, you have to point to the 6th row. This is a bug, but you can account for it.

Comment: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/issues/392

Answer (score 4):

I think they broke that part of the copy functions with version 4.  See this:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15068

So, could just manually set the style ids after the copy:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Copy_Styles_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853046/epplus-copy-style-to-a-range

    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[] {new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (int)) });

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] = i; row[1] = i * 10; row[2] = i * 100; 
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\test.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        const int rowCount = 5;
        const int startRow = 18;

        //Show the data
        var xlsSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        xlsSheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

        //Throw in some styles for testing
        xlsSheet.Row(startRow).Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        xlsSheet.Row(startRow).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Aqua);
        xlsSheet.Cells[String.Format("A{0}:C{0}", startRow)].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);

        //Insert new rows
        xlsSheet.InsertRow(startRow, rowCount);

        //Copy the cells and manually set the style IDs
        var copyrow = startRow + rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            var row = startRow + i;
            xlsSheet.Cells[String.Format("{0}:{0}", copyrow)].Copy(xlsSheet.Cells[String.Format("{0}:{0}", row)]);
            xlsSheet.Row(row).StyleID = xlsSheet.Row(copyrow).StyleID;
        }

        //May not be needed but cant hurt
        xlsSheet.Cells.Worksheet.Workbook.Styles.UpdateXml();

        //save it
        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define a work sheet like this :

```
   string sheetName="Your Sheet Name";
   ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);
```

Then you can use the following code to change the style of whole sheet:

```
      Color colFromHex = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B8C9E9");
      ws.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
      ws.Cells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);
      ws.Cells.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Medium;
      // . . . . .
```

And use the following code to change the style of a range:

```
       Color colFromHex = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B8C9E9");
       ws.Cells["A1:H16"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
       ws.Cells["A1:H16"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(colFromHex);
       ws.Cells["A1:H16"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Medium;
```

Comment: There are 5-6 different colors and cell styles in the ranges, thats why i was looking to apply the style from range.