# EPPLUS shift down a row

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, epplus

I'm working on a migration project from the  **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** library To EPPlus in **c#** and what I want it's to get the the equivalent of this code using **EEplus** library.

I'm using a template XLSX file with 7 rows and depending rows data I want the insert a new row with the same style.

```
if (MyData.Tables[0].Rows.Count>3) 
            {
                for (int j=1;j<MyData.Tables[0].Rows.Count-3;j++)
                {
                    for (int i1=1;i1<29;i1++)
                    {
                        EXCEL.Range TheRange = (EXCEL.Range) ws.Cells[7,i1];
                        TheRange.Insert(EXCEL.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown,missing);

                    }
                }
            }
```

[view xlsx template](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4atrkOwAJq5c3lKRTVuZWxrck0/view?usp=sharing)
and the result with
[Epplus without shiftdown](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4atrkOwAJq5dV90dVdKZDdqbnc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Inserting rows seems to still have issues with copying the style event in the latest version (4.1.0).  See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853046/epplus-copy-style-to-a-range

Comment: th solution is to use  : ExcelWorksheet.InsertRow(rowFrom, number of rows to add , copy style from row N°);