# EPPlus - Copy cell formatting to new cell

Tags: format, copy, epplus

Is there an easy way to copy the format of a cell (eg background color, font type, borders etc...) from one cell to another with EPPlus v4.5.3.3?

Ive noticed the following question from a while back, but the accepted answer doesn't make any sense to me!
[EPPlus: Copy Style to a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853046/epplus-copy-style-to-a-range/34299694)

At the moment I'm having to hard code each individual property across one by one using a custom function, but was hoping there was a better way to do it? Im also hitting some limitations with this method, particularly around colours, because if I have used a more unusual colour (eg picked from a colour wheel) then I cant seem to set all the color properties on the new cell in order to replicate the colour (they are marked as "get" only", eg Theme")

```
private void ApplyStyleToCell(OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelStyle cellStyle, ExcelRangeBase cellsToApplyTo )
    {
        // You cant write the whole ExcelStyle object to a new cell, so we need to update each part of the style individually
        cellsToApplyTo.Style.Border = cellStyle.Border;

        cellsToApplyTo.Style.Fill.PatternType = cellStyle.Fill.PatternType;
        if(cellStyle.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb != null){ cellsToApplyTo.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + cellStyle.Fill.BackgroundColor.Rgb)); }
        cellsToApplyTo.Style.Fill.PatternType = cellStyle.Fill.PatternType;

        cellsToApplyTo.Style.Font.Bold = cellStyle.Font.Bold;
        if (cellStyle.Font.Color.Rgb != null && cellStyle.Font.Color.Rgb != "") { cellsToApplyTo.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + cellStyle.Font.Color.Rgb)); }
        if (cellStyle.Font.Color.Rgb != null && cellStyle.Font.Color.Theme != "") { cellsToApplyTo.Style.Font.Color.Theme = cellStyle.Font.Color.Theme; }
        cellsToApplyTo.Style.Font.Family = cellStyle.Font.Family;
        cellsToApplyTo.Style.Font.Italic = cellStyle.Font.Italic; 
        // etc...
}
```